# Why are my paragraph elements different sizes?

Tags: css, wordpress

I cannot work out what is going on here.  The paragraphs with class="caption" on this page are not lining up and I cannot work out why.  The page is [here](http://nicolaelvin.com/community/gallery-2/)

Comment: I'm not seeing *any* paragraphs on that page at all.

Comment: its the text in the main section - holmfirth scenery etc

Comment: yes I don't want you to click on holmfirth scenery, its the page in my link http://nicolaelvin.com/community/gallery-2/ I am on about, the actual text "holmfirth scenery" and "holmfirth festivals" is the paragraph elements I am on about

Comment: Ah! I...feel like such an idiot now... =/

Comment: lol its ok, I'll forgive you if you can work out why there's the extra space...

Comment: The extra space (in Chrome 18/WinXP) is because the height of the first `a` (containing the `img`) is `186px` and the second is `179px`. Why *that* is, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Yep I just realised that.  I cannot see what is causing the extra height and both images are the same height

Comment: Its ok I have realised what it was, there's 2 different classes on each image and one has float left, so this is shrinking the container.  Phew!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second image has a the class *alignLeft* applied to it, which the first does not. This class includes the CSS property `float:left` which removes the inline status of the image, and hence the extra pixels that browsers put under any inline element. This resuls in the height of the wrapping link tag to drop from 186px to 179px.

Comment: thanks I just realised that too!  It's wordpress, it adds so many classes on, I thought I'd got them all covered.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the CSS "tag" selectors within your CSS files. As far as I can see there exists an overall margin-bottom value (a value of 1.625em which means a pretty long distance between paragraphs) which has been assigned for all p elements.